# Using ERB variables to DRY up html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I want to DRY up my ERB with the below:

```
<div>
  <section class="item">
    +
    <%= render partial: "layouts/list-item" %>
  </section>
  <section class="item">
    +
    <%= render partial: "layouts/list-item" %>
  </section>
  <section class="item">
    +
    <%= render partial: "layouts/list-item" %>
  </section>
</div>
```

I want to do something like this to not have to repeat myself but it's throwing an error. Do I have to use a for loop instead?

```
</div>
  <% item = '      <section class="item">
          +
          <%= render partial: "layouts/list-item" %>
        </section>'
  %>
  <%= item * 3 %>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please post the error message?

Comment: 'unterminated regexp meets end of file' says something's wrong with my </div> at the end

Comment: Why do you need the pluses inside the html?

Comment: it's the text I want to show for the pluses

Comment: you want to DRY but you repeat rendering with partial without any parametrization anyway, so what is the content which is going to be rerendered and duplicated actually?

Answer (score 2):

You could use :

```
<div>
  < ["", "+", "+"].each do |item| >
    <section class="item">
      <%= item >
      <%= render partial: "layouts/list-item" %>
    </section>
  < end >
</div>
```

For anything more complex, you could define instance variables in controller, and use basic logic in views (as the loop in this example) to display the data from those variables.

Data should come from a model via controller, html elements should be in views or helpers.